# (had) quit and resumed learning UNTIL

Tags: past-tense

1 I started learning Chinese when I was a child but I **quit and resumed learning** it a few times **until** I matriculated in University.

2 I started learning Chinese when I was a child but I **had quit and resumed learning** it a few times **until** I matriculated in University.

I think that both are correct? Do you agree?

Comment: #2 could mean you did the quitting before you did the learning, not logical. Or maybe you quit and resumed before Uni. Still not helping. Generally in life and language, if you can do without complicating things, that's your best bet.

Comment: Isn't it true that "until" prompts the use of a perfect tense: I had visited the church often until I left the town.

Comment: You could even have *...I had quit and **had** resumed learning it a few times* for the second one. But they all mean the same - so as @YosefBaskin suggests, *Why complicate things?*

Comment: It's just that "UNTIL" (as I think) requires a perfect tense.

Comment: Good example when you don't need fancy: I [had] visited the church often until I left the town. An adult can figure that the visiting occurred only before the leaving, not after. Trusting our audience is a gift to their intelligence.

Comment: "UNTIL" requires a perfect tense? No. I ate until I puked. I lived well until I died (I didn't live in any way after I died, so no need to clear up the sequence with *had lived*)

Comment: "I had visited the church often **before** I left the town."